# Proof of Synge theorem without homotopy

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Can the following statement be proven without the use of homotopy?

*If $(M,g)$ is a closed, orientable Riemannian manifold with even dimension $m$ and positive sectional curvature then $M$ is simply connected.*

When I look it up different sources (for example: Petersens book, [these lecture notes](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~wangzuoq/635W12/Notes/Lec%2032.pdf)) all used homotopy classes, but I'm not familiar with this concept.

**So, can it be proven not using homotopy classes?**

Comment: How do you define simply connected without homotopy?

Comment: I thought, it could probably be shown that under given circumstances a Riemannian manifold is isomorphic to some surface which is simply connected.

Comment: That still doesn't get around the issue that you simply can't define simply connected without homotopy....

Comment: OK, so do you know a book which explains this well?

Comment: @XiTong : try J. Jost's Riemannian geometry and geometric analysis. Basically you need the fact that every class $[\gamma]$ can be represented by a geodesic. That is proved in the book.

Comment: Look at do Carmo's book: Riemannian Geometry, p. 206. With the homotopy class it's much more easier though!